# How do I find a philosophy to define my current beliefs?

Tags: self

I recently went from Christianity to Agnosticism. I already know what I do and don't believe:

I don't believe in fate. I believe that people should respect each other because life is short. I don't believe that life has inherent value. I believe that the God of Christianity exists, but that he doesn't interfere with human existence. (I don't like Him because of my experiences with religion, Christians, prayer, and logic.)

Is there an appropriate label to put on my beliefs?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear --it sounds like you've already defined yourself as an agnostic former Christian.  What else are you looking for?

Comment: these questions have come up a few times, and don't necessarily get closed. so list what you currently believe. unless, ofc, you're asking for agnostic philosophers to read :) ?

Comment: I don't believe in fate. I believe that people should respect each other because life is short. I don't believe that life has inherent value. I believe that the God of Christianity exists, but that he doesn't interfere with human existence. I'm not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: If you believe that God does not interfere with human existence it sounds less like the God of Christianity, and more like [Epicurean gods](http://www.iep.utm.edu/epicur/#SH3e). Incidentally, Epicurus did not believe in fate either (which was unusual in antiquity). It is very unclear what you mean by "God", but if it is anything like Christian version you can not believe in it *and* be agnostic. Perhaps you'd prefer  [apatheism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apatheism), plain religious indifference.

Comment: I believe in the God of Christianity, but I don't like Him because of my experiences with religion, Christians, prayer, and logic... I'll look at apatheism.

Comment: @ChrisSunami I'm looking for a label.

Comment: @user3293056 not so much, no

Comment: i don't really understand @user16053 but good luck

Comment: I would suggest that philosophy is about determining what to believe,rather than labeling what you do believe. If you want to put a name to your beliefs you'll have to tell us what they are. At the moment all we know is that you're agnostic on God. This is not a philosophical position but the absence of one, an honest admission of not knowing which one to endorse.

Comment: I don't have a name but how about "I believe in God but I can't bring myself to worship Him?".

Comment: Why are we looking for labels for ourselves?

Comment: @Alex - Your position is interesting. In the past I also could not believe in a God that needs to be worshiped. Then I realised that worship is a psychological technique that benefits the worshiper, not something God needs and not something that depends on his existence. A useful example is 'guru-worship' in Buddhist practice. The guru is worshiped as a method of development but is a fiction, You endorse the idea of God but not of worship, others endorse worship but not the idea of God. The difference may indicate whether we think God or 'the Real' is apart from us or identical.

Comment: @PeterJ That's not quite my personal belief but a suggestion for user6053 given the question and comments. My view is closer to something like "I see no reason for me to worship as god either doesn't exist, isn't listening, isn't able to make any difference or is a nasty piece of work". I wouldn't presume to endorse or promote this view. It just happens to be the one I settled on.

Comment: See related question: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/29063/on-atheists-who-are-sympathetic-to-religion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually called ***Deism*** or Natural Religion, to use the older designation. Basically the notion of a philanthropic, fellow loving, life, rejecting Salvation in the next world as a principle of life in this world.